How to update view from @ObservableObject without using it?
I have an ObservableObject that fetches feature toggles async from our API. The feature toggle is, amongst other things, used to switch between views in my Tab View.
The selected tab view doesen't reevaluate when feature toggles are done loading.
FeatureToggle is an enum: string.
And are fetched like this:
class FeatureToggleController: ObservableObject {
    @Published var featureToggles: [FeatureToggle] = []
    
    private var networkController: NetworkController = Container.networkController
    private var errorHandler = Container.errorHandler
    
    func isFeatureToggleOn(_ featureToggle: FeatureToggle) -> Bool {
        return featureToggles.contains(featureToggle)
    }
    
    func fetchFeatureToggles() async -> Void {
        let result: Result<[String], OperatorAppError> = await networkController.getUrlDataResult(.featureToggles)
        switch result {
        case .success(let fts):
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.featureToggles = fts.compactMap { FeatureToggle(rawValue:$0) }
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            errorHandler.handleError(title: "Error while fetching feature toggles", error: error)
        }
    }
}

My tab view looks like this:
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: selectedTab) {
            ForEach(Tab.allCases) { tab in
                tab.destination
                    .tag(tab as Tab?)
                    .tabItem { tab.getIcon()  }
                    
            }
        }
    }

In my TabView I have this switch:
enum Tab: Hashable, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    case otherTabs
    case tabInQuestion
    
    var id: Tab { self }
}

extension Tab {
    @ViewBuilder
    var destination: some View {
        switch self {
        case .otherTabs:
            OtherView()
        case .tabInQuestion:
            if (Container.featureToggleController.isFeatureToggleOn(.isFeature1Enabled)) 
            {
                FeatureToggledView()
            } else {
                NormalView()
            }
        }
    }
}


The FeatureToggleController is declared as singleton and injected via a simple poor mans injection / container:
class Container {
    
    // Mark: - Single instance members
    public static var networkController: NetworkController = NetworkControllerImplementation()
    public static var featureToggleController: FeatureToggleController = FeatureToggleController()
    // Mark: - Multiple instance members    
    public static var errorHandler: ErrorHandler {
        ErrorHandlerImplementation(
            logController: logController,
            alertController: alertController)
    }
}


After the feature toggles finish loading, this tab view is not re-evaluated.
Since the isFeatureToggledOn(...) is using the published property on the observable object FeatureToggleController, I would assume so.
But maybe I'm loosing the binding somewhere?
Update:
So, the observable object FeatureToggleController is instantiated by my poor mans injection Container and there is no state held in any view. This is why there is not subscribed to the published  list.
Holding a state object in the enum extension is not possible, so I added a View to do the view switching and accessed the published list directly instead of a wrapper function:
struct FeatureToggledSwitchView: View {
    @StateObject private var featureToggleController = Container.featureToggleController
    
    var body: some View {
        if (featureToggleController.featureToggles.contains(.isFeature1Enabled)) {
            FeatureToggledView()
        } else {
            NormalView()
        }
    }
}

Instantiating this in my Tab's destination extension triggers re-evaluation of the whole FeatureToggledSwitchView content as expected.
extension Tab {
    @ViewBuilder
    var destination: some View {
        switch self {
        case .otherTabs:
            OtherView()
        case .tabInQuestion:
            FeatureToggledSwitchView()
        }
    }
}

Which makes perfectly sense since the feature toggle controller state is now anchored in a view.
Only problem left is that i get a navigation error, but I guess that's unrelated to this and related to mu NavigationStack implementation.
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Layout requested for visible navigation bar, <SwiftUI.UIKitNavigationBar: 0x105b558e0; baseClass = UINavigationBar; frame = (0 53.6667; 393 96); opaque = NO; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000002db5a0>> delegate=0x10795be00, when the top item belongs to a different navigation bar. topItem = <UINavigationItem: 0x105b64c90> title='Feature Toggled View' style=navigator leftItemsSupplementBackButton trailingItemGroups=0x600000cbd200 largeTitleDisplayMode=always, navigation bar = <SwiftUI.UIKitNavigationBar: 0x105b6cb50; baseClass = UINavigationBar; frame = (0 0; 393 96); opaque = NO; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000002bab40>> delegate=0x10782b800, possibly from a client attempt to nest wrapped navigation controllers.'

can you show how you declare your FeatureToggleController in your view hierarchy, and how you pass it to the other views and receive it in the view with your TabView

@workingdogsupportUkraine Added the declaration. It's a simple singleton accessed thru a container. That's how I do all injections.

@workingdogsupportUkraine Ahh... You sparked my mind. The FeatureToggleController is stateless. Maybe if I hold the FeatureToggleController as a StateObject in the Tab, it will re-evaluate? The problem here is that the Tab is an enum, and I can't hold stored properties in that... Any ideas?

For an ObservableObject class to have its @Published observed, you need to declare it
in a View using @StateObject and pass this data model to other views
using for example @ObservedObject or @EnvironmentObject.
Have a look at this Apple link Monitoring data it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app. Note, I would not create or use Views in a enum.

@workingdogsupportUkraine Thanks, I'm aware how that works. Do you know if there is any other way I can subscribe to the published property manually?
I.e. from code?

not clear what you are trying to do, a minimal code would help. If you know how it works, why do you have a ObservableObject in a class and as a singleton as well public static var featureToggleController: .... does not make sense.

@workingdogsupportUkraine because I want to be able to inject ObservableObjects from my container to only use the constructor and dependencies in one place. And this actually works pretty well once stored in a StateObject. Updated the question with that exact example, which solves the problem. Thanks for the pointers in the right direction. Please convert it to an answer if you want the points.
The extended code in the question is because I always get responses with too little context. So I tried to make it elaborate.

Don't worry about an answer, you got things working, that's good enough.

For async/await in SwiftUI it’s .task which replaces StateObject

.task "Adds an asynchronous task to perform before this view appears", it
does not replace StateObject, it is clearly explained here
.task
